# Rails how to get a particular error message on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, message

I'm actually having a hard time figure out how to get a first error message related to a particular association.
In my form, I must display errors under every related fields such as :

```
= f.text_field :price, class: 'form-control'
  - if @item.errors.has_key? :price
    = content_tag :span, @item.errors[:price].first, class: 'form-error'
```

This works fine on model base attributes. However, my Item model is linked to another model via a polymorphic association. When displaying `errors.full_messages`, I get `["Attachments name doit être rempli(e)"]`. Here is the relation :

```
has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
validates :name, presence: true
```

How can I do in order to get the error returned by this association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution using `@post.errors.inspect`. Here is what I needed to do :

```
@post.errors[:'attachments.name'].first
```

Hope it will help poeple facing the same issue